# Getting a error defining MySql 5.1 stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am defining a stored procedure and it throws an error at DECLARE variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc()
BEGIN

DECLARE venueid VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE i INT;
```

Heres the Error -

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'DECLARE
>   venueid VARCHAR(50);

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
drop procedure if exists test_proc;

delimiter #

create procedure test_proc()
begin

declare venueid varchar(50);
declare i int default 0;

  -- do more stuff

end #

delimiter ;

call test_proc();
```